# Many to many with polymorphic association doesn't work in both directions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

I am implementig the system that enable user to follow the "followable"( in my case these may be an event, place or other user).

My idea:

**Follow** model holds the user_id, followable type and followale_id(join table)

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Event**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
  has_many :users, through: :follows
end
```

**Place**

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
  has_many :users, through: :follows    
end
```

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows
  has_many :events, through: :follows, source: :followable, source_type: "Event"
  has_many :places, through: :follows, source: :followable, source_type: "Place"
  has_many :users, through: :follows, source: :followable, source_type: "User"
end
```

The problem is that the realtion works only in one direction, **i can do:**

```
user.follows.create(followable:event1) #follow event1
user.follows.create(followable:place1) #follow place1
user.follows.create(followable:user1)  #follow user1
user.follows # displays all following relations user has established
```

**But, i cannot do**:

```
event1.follows #return follow objects(some user - event1 pairs)
event1.users #return all of the users that follow this event
user1.users  #return all of the users that user1 follows, the most confusing part..
```

All of the aboves return nil.

How should i establish the relations to make it work in both directions?
Also, i'd like to hear some remarks on how to improve this idea, beacouse it's the first time i'm playin around with more complex realtions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Quick thought: are you sure you're not seeing a stale cache of `event1.follows`? What happens when you try `event1.follows(true)`? (The `true` here tells ActiveRecord to reload the association rather than use its cache if it has it)

Comment: Output: #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: What about `event1.follows.to_sql`?

Comment: "SELECT \"follows\".* FROM \"follows\" WHERE \"follows\".\"followable_id\" = 1 AND \"follows\".\"followable_type\" = 'Event'"

Comment: That looks right to me. So if that query does not return any `Event`s that implies that the line `user.follows.create(followable:event1)` did not successfully save `event1`'s id and type to the newly created `Follow` record. Can you see what the SQL log is when you do that `create`? Or what the return value is of that statement?

Comment: (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  `SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "follows" ("followable_id", "followable_type", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["followable_id", 1], ["followable_type", "Event"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-05-15 14:21:30.447242"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-15 14:21:30.447242"]] `
   (75.3ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Follow id: 1, user_id: 1, followable_id: 1, followable_type: "Event", created_at: "2016-05-15 14:21:30", updated_at: "2016-05-15 14:21:30">

Comment: and when i type `user.follows` it's ok -  proper row is displayed

Comment: It looks like this created the first `Follow` record. Did you explicitly reset your db or delete old records? If you hadn't I would have expected this `Follow` to have an id greater than 1. If that's what's going on, that would explain it -- for some reason the previous create failed. If you did delete / reset db records, then that's a bit of a stumper and I'd try again after restarting the console (just to make sure some old cached definition wasn't hiding somewhere I didn't think of)

Comment: (Note that `user.follows` can display objects even when they are not yet saved to the db -- do all of those `Follow`s have an id?)

Comment: yes, after reseting db and console event is working in both directions but I still cannot do `user.users` to check which users are following me..Looks like there is some conflict in my relations when refering from user to user..

Comment: Basically the problem is that you are not differentiating between follows where the user is in `user_id` and those where the user is in the `followable_id` which is why `user1.users` does not return what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start off with the User model as its the trickiest:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows, source: :user
  has_many :follows_as_fallowable, 
                    class_name: 'Follow',
                    as: :followable

  has_many :followers, through: :follows_as_fallowable,
                       source: :user

  # other users the user is following                     
  has_many :followed_users, through: :follows,
                            source: :followable,
                            source_type: 'User'
end
```

Note that we need two different relationships to `follows` due to the fact that the user can be in either column depending on if the user is the follower or the object being followed.

We can now do a simple test to check if the relationship is setup properly:

```
joe = User.create(name: 'Joe')
jill = User.create(name: 'Jill')
joe.followers << jill
jill.followed_users.include?(joe) # true
joe.followers.include?(jill) # true
```

To then setup a the bi-directional relation between users and a followable model you would do:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
  has_many :followers, through: :follows,
                       source: :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :followed_events, through: :follows,
                             source: :followable,
                             source_type: 'Event'
end
```

The relations in the followed model (Event) are pretty much the same in every model so you can easily extract it to a module for reuse:

```
# app/models/concerns/followable.rb
module Followable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :follows, as: :followable
    has_many :followers, through: :follows,
                         source: :user
  end
end

class Event < ActiceRecord::Base
  include Followable
end

class Place < ActiceRecord::Base
  include Followable
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, but have a problem with understanding one thing:
`has_many :followers, through: :follows_as_fallowable,
                       source: :user`
How does rails know from which table to select? It doesn't deduce based on association name, it doesn't take it from class_name argument. So how does it know that it should return user record?

Comment: `source: :user` tells it to get the`belongs_to :user` relation on Follow which is not polymorphic.